# How to make asp.net lable word wrap

Tags: css, asp.net

I need to make the text in an asp.net label control word wrap.  I have found a number of online examples, but for some reason they are not working for me.  Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong and how to make the text/words wrap?

```
<asp:Label CssClass="checkboxlist-categories" ID="itemCheckBoxLabel" runat="server" Text="a;klj a;jfaf d dkdkdkdk d  dkdkddksks sss"></asp:Label>
```

and this is the style:

```
    .checkboxlist-categories {
    width: 50px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
    color: red;
}
```

## Thank you

I found a good answer here:
[enter link description here](https://weblogs.asp.net/vikram/wrapping-text-line-in-a-label-control)

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Try using this instead:     display:inline-block

Comment: Or use a text box that is not enabled with the border hidden - it will wrap for you.